# Error: (index):186 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

Tags: django, ajax

I am getting this error while sending my form through Ajax in Django

Error: (index):186 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

in line

```
data= formdata
```

Can you help me figure out the solution.

```
    uploadBtn.addEventListener('click', e=>{
                e.preventDefault()
                progressBox.classList.toggle('not-visible', false)
    
                var formdata = new FormData()
                formdata.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrftoken)
                formdata.append('fileA', FileA.files[0])
                formdata.append('a_year', year.value) 
    
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '',
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    data = formdata,
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response)
                    },
                    error: function(response){
                        console.log(response)
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData:false,
                })     
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a colon not `=`.

Like so:

```
data: formdata,
```

not:

```
data = formdata,
```

Comment: @jas we all have them days, dont worry!